# Mobile Safari submit with enter key

Tags: forms, ipad, click, mobile-safari, enter

I am using an iPad with a bluetooth keyboard and am having some troubles.  I basically have a website that after tapping search, pops up with a modal. The modal contains a summary of information & two buttons - a cancel and a print.  My hope is to have the "Enter" key mean the user clicked on the "Print" button. I've tried going the javascript route with click triggers and such, and I've also tried making it into a form with a submit button but mobile safari likes neither.  It seems like it requires that I touch the screen again before pressing enter to work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated..